# Mastering event bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-bubbling

Lets say we have a HTML structure like this

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="nested">
        <span id="someElement"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and our goal is to have an event listener on the `#container` **only** ! So, we bind a listener (jQuery code)

```
$("#container").on('click', function(event) {
    alert("container was clicked");
});
```

That works of course, but my problem with this approach is that, since events usually bubble up, that listener will also fire if we actually click on `#nested` or `#someElement`. My current solution to **only** handle the click when the `#container` is clicked is to compare `this` with `event.target`

```
$("#container").on('click', function(event) {
    if(this === event.target) {
        alert("container was clicked");
    }
});
```

My question: Is that considered "best practice" ? Is there a better way with jQuery to accomplish the same result "out of the box" ?

Example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/FKX7p/

Comment: IMO, this is the best practice.

Comment: @jSang: Actually the inner elements don't have any listeners on a click. Is that considered best practice ? bind every element just to stop the propagation ?

Comment: I don't see any better approach either, in fact, I was about to post that as an answer until I saw you already have that code.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to prevent events from bubbling up is to use event.stopPropagation();

```
$("#container").on('click', function(event) {
    alert("container was clicked");
})
.children().on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I think the advantage of using this approach is that if you want to attach another event to the nested div, you can just use

```
$("#nested").on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // some action
});

$("#container").on('click', function(event) {
    alert("container was clicked");
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```
$("#container").click(function(){
    alert("container was clicked");
}).children().click(function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

But your solution is better. [jsfiddle.net/FKX7p/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/FKX7p/2/) (with return false) OR [jsfiddle.net/FKX7p/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/FKX7p/3/) (using stopPropagation)

I prefer use return in your example (code becomes easier to read):

```
if(this !== event.target) return;
```

Comment: In addition use `event.CurrentTarget !== event.Target` instead of `this` when required, due to the possible context change of `this` when using jQuery.proxy: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: The alternative solution is worse, as it adds a lot of event handlers.

Comment: @naugtur I agree with you, but before `on` function this solution was popular.

Comment: if popular != good then yes ;) Comparing target and currentTarget is way better. (notice I'm not giving you a -1; mostly because I used to do stuff like that)

Comment: @naugtur Yes, you're right. I want to note that nobody give me -1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which one work's faster but it make sense that the next code will be better:

```
$("#container").click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id && e.target.id !== "container") return false;
});
```

Comment: Now i'ts only check the identifier, with complex selectors i can't see another way except comparing the objects